# Alternatives for MemoryStore express.io

Tags: node.js, session, express.io

When running node js in production mode, this warning is logged :

```
Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
```

Doing a brief research, i found that i should use other alternatives for session storage by passing ***express-session-mongo*** or ***express-session-redis***.
My questions :

- Are this solutions built for ***expressJs*** working with ***express.io*** ?
- Is there a solution to solve the problem without using one of theese ? As you can see, using one of them will force me to install mongo or redis which is not good in my case.

*Thank You !*

Comment: Express.io is fairly outdated, however there is a regularly updated [fork](https://github.com/sibartlett/express.oi) maintained by someone else.

Comment: So, you want to say that the best thing is to abandon it in favor of espress + socket.io ?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is use the updated fork, but your option is a possibility too.

Comment: I solved it by using "cookie-session" library, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by using the `cookie-session` library, i simply flowed the tutorial.
[cookie-session on github](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest backing your session's with a database.  I would use Redis, CouchDB/Cloudant, memcached, or Mongo.

The reason express is giving that error is the in memory database is only available on the current node you are running and if you scale your application the session data will not be available on other nodes.

Check out http://passportjs.org/, there are some modules to help you store the session data into an external resource.

Comment: Using "cookie-session" library solved the problem, you can find the link in my awnser. Thanks !